# How does starting torque increase by increasing rotor resistance?

Tags: induction-motor

As the formula below shows that the torque is both directly and inversely proportional to the rotor resistance. However, since it's inversely proportional to the square of the resistance, it is the predominant relation.
Increasing the rotor resistance reduces the torque.
[image]

But, in the below figure it gives the opposite effect, whereby increasing the rotor resistance tends to increase the torque.

[image]

Since the rotor resistance is R2/s, the slip is maximum at starting i.e. close to 1 and reduces as the motor speed increases and at 1750 rpm, the slip is 1/36, so, the rotor resistance will become very high

36*R2

This means increasing the rotor resistance actually reduces the torque both at low and high speeds.

Am I right?

Source:

FE Reference Handbook 10.0.1

by NCEES

ISBN 978-1-947801-11-0

Comment: When you say this about the graph: *whereby increasing the rotor resistance tends to increase the torque.* - I don't see what you see. OK you mean it increases the starting torque yes?

Comment: @Andy aka in the graph the torque if you compare R4 and R1, yes starting torque for R4 is higher but also the torque up to about 1250 rpm it's larger than R1 torque, then, they reverse and R1 torque becomes larger. Right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Key points from Fitzgerald, Kingsley, Umans:

1. In the normal operating range, increasing R2 increases the rotor impedance, necessitating higher slip for a given torque.
2. Slip at maximum torque is directly proportional to R2 but the maximum torque is not changed by changing R2.
3. R2/s = R2 + R2(1-s)/s
4. The power dissipated in R2 represents rotor resistance losses.
5. The power dissipated in R2(1-s)/s represents the electrical power converted to mechanical power, torque x speed.